# Grape/GAP algorithm for an isomorphic graph for a permutation

Tags: graph-theory, gap, graph-isomorphism

Problem: Given a graph G (as an adjacency matrix or a grape graph object), and a permutation $\pi \in S_n$. Find an isomorphic graph $G'$  as another adjacency matrix, under $\pi$.

The concept is fairly straightforward, but repeated need for such a result requires an algorithm to do a quick analysis. I was hoping somebody might already have a GAP function for this.

For example, a series of transpositions, 
$\psi_n, \psi_{n-1}, \cdots , \psi_1$
such that $\pi = \psi_n \psi_{n-1} \cdots  \psi_1$, applied to the 
adjacency matrix could accomplish the result. In the actual GAP implementation (that I have tried) requires a transposition of the adj matrix (rows<-> column) as well, for each $\psi_i$ applied to the adj matrix. 
Thank you.

Note: Actually Grape is not really needed to modify the adjacency matrix, A. Grape would be a good tool to test the isomorphism, and to test that the transformation to A was indeed correct.

Comment: Hmm if A is the adjacency matrix and P is the matrix of pi(in the column i has the pi(i) vector of canonical basses), the matrix will be PAP^-1, right?

Comment: Could you please provide some hint/explanation as to the logic of this result? (my question was a little ambiguous-- I did not mean $\pi$ to be given as a matrix, but no harm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please note that there is a tag `gap` here for GAP questions. Also, it helps to chose more generic tag as `graph-theory` for such question. If you will look at other questions in `graph-isomorphism` tag, you may see that perhaps your question does not fit there. Are you asking how to find adjacency matrix of a new graph, relabelling it accordingly to the permutation $pi \in S_n$? Also note that you can edit your question to make it clearer, so if you agree that you question is ambiguous then please go ahead and edit it to make it more clear!

Comment: Thank you Alex for all your suggestions and updating the tags. Have noted, and already revised the question to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would do this with Grape, but you can do it with the [Digraphs](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/digraphs.php) package. If your Grape graph is stored in the variable *G*, then you can convert it to a digraph by doing:

```
Digraph(G);
```

And if *p* a permutation whose moved points are a subset of the vertices of *G*, then you can act on *G* using the function [OnDigraphs](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/digraphs/doc/chap7_mj.html#X808972017C486F1F).